# ERROR: Webscraping with Puppeteer - Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the URLs for all returned search items in RightMove. The page is:

https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E61299&insId=2&radius=0.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false

I am using Puppeteer to try and do this but keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'getProperty' of undefined"

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapePropery(URL)  {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  try {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  
  const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="property-105155516"]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/a');
  const href = await el.getProperty('href')
  const hrefTxt = await href.jsonValue();

  console.log({hrefTxt});

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } finally {

  browser.close();

};
}

scrapePropery('https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/find.html?searchType=SALE&locationIdentifier=REGION%5E61299&insId=2&radius=0.0&minPrice=&maxPrice=&minBedrooms=&maxBedrooms=&displayPropertyType=&maxDaysSinceAdded=&_includeSSTC=on&sortByPriceDescending=&primaryDisplayPropertyType=&secondaryDisplayPropertyType=&oldDisplayPropertyType=&oldPrimaryDisplayPropertyType=&newHome=&auction=false');
```

**What am I doing wrong?** I've tried scraping different elements but I keep getting the same error, I've been successful using the code I've written on other sites like Amazon (with minor changes to the property in .getProperty Method) but no luck with RightMove.

**Any ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: I don't see that id on in the html for the page.

Comment: Thanks QHarr, looks like that is happening because the first property (which I’ve used as the ID) in the search list is a featured which changes. Hadn’t noticed that and this is likely to be my problem... a change in approach is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the xPath being used is incorrect and this caused an undefined response.